# matlab adding single legend for multiple data

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

```
figure(1);
hold on;
na=4;
circle_X = [0 0 5 5]'; 
circle_Y = [0 3 0 3]';

for a = 1:na
        r=0.3;                               
        N=100;                            
        theta=linspace(0, 2*pi, N); 
        cx=r*cos(theta)+circle_X(a); 
        cy=r*sin(theta)+circle_Y(a);  
       plot3(cx , cy, 300*ones(N), 'r', 'linewidth', 2,'DisplayName',sprintf('circle'));     
end
legend('show');
```

I want to draw 4 circles and add a single legend 'circle' indicating 4 circles all at once, without using "legend('circle')".
For now the legend looks like this
[image]

how should I change the code?

Comment: What's wrong with `legend('circle')`?

Comment: @SardarUsama That's a good question, I don't know what OP wants but I can think of cases that you want to build a generic function that will serve some different purposes, and not all this code is written in the same script...

Comment: I am gonna add more plots on this figure. If I use command 'legend' for these circles and use legend command again, all the legend I made before is initialized. @SardarUsama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need `plot3`, you can achieve the same figure with `plot`, and probably the long legend is because of that.
just change the line of plot to that:

```
plot(cx , cy, 'r', 'linewidth', 2,'DisplayName','circle');
```

Now, the legend will have 4 entries because you draw four objects. If you want a single entry you have some ways:

1. add the legend inside the loop, after an `if` statement. For example,

   `if a==1 ,
    legend('show');
   end`
2. get handles for your plots, and legend just one of them. It can be done directly from `legend`, but then you will need to specify the string:

   `for....
   h(a)=plot...
   end
   legend(h(1),'circle')`
3. get handles like in part 2, and if you don't want specify the string 'circle', you can use the undocumented `hasbehavior`:

   `for...
   h(a)=plot...
   end
   hasbehavior(h(2),'legend',false);
   hasbehavior(h(3),'legend',false);
   hasbehavior(h(4),'legend',false);
   l=legend('show');`

Comment: Thanks for kind answer! I used plot3 because I have to add surf afterwards which might cover the circle plotted before. For the same reason, if I use command 'legend' for these circles, I can't apply legend for my surf. As legend is only available once for a axis.

Comment: So it helps you, or you still stuck with the legend for other 3d object? I would recommend get handles to all your plots, then legend exactly those you want, with their handles

Comment: I solved the problem by using plot handles! thanks for help!

Comment: Great, glad to help!